# Swap image depending on referrer

Tags: javascript, image, swap, referrer

I am trying to swap out a background image depending on the referrer. For instance, when someone visits from Facebook, I want to display a different image than I would otherwise. I've hobbled together the following code, but it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
if (document.referrer !== "https://www.facebook.com/") {
 document.getElementById('modImage').src = "image1.jpg";
} 
else if(image=2) {
document.getElementById('modImage').src = "image2.jpg";
}
```

I gave the the target image a an ID of modImage.

Comment: In what way is it not working @BradleyB?

Comment: `if(image=2)` is assignment.  You want `==` probably or maybe `===`.  Please clarify what `image` is.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! When I visit the page from facebook, the image is not swapping out. Also, I am not sure if the else if(image=2) is correct. I want the else if to be if the user comes from anywhere other than facebook...

Comment: Then you don't want an `else if {...}`, you just want `else {...}`. `else if(image=2){...}` means, if they aren't coming from Facebook and the assignment of 2 to `image` results in a truthy value, do what's between the `{ }`.

Comment: Yep, delete the `if(image=2)` and see if that's what you needed

Comment: Also, bear in mind that `referrer` can be blank if `noreferrer` is used.

Comment: Thanks again everyone! I deleted the if(image-2), but it's still not working. I'm wondering if the  document.referrer !== is correct? Does that mean exact match? Maybe is should be something that means contains the url?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can just lose the "if" on your else if:

```
if (document.referrer !== "https://www.facebook.com/")
   document.getElementById('modImage').src = "image1.jpg";
else
   document.getElementById('modImage').src = "image2.jpg";
```

Or were you trying to check if image2.jpg is available before setting the src to it?

Also, you might be better off using a regular expression to see if the referrer **contains** "facebook", rather than exactly matching "https://www.facebook.com/", like so:

```
if (!/facebook\.com/.test(document.referrer))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I changed the code like you suggest. It's still not working, though. Any idea what else could be wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: What exactly is not working?
Is the src always set to image1 or image2?
Is the src not being set at all?
Is the src being set, but is no image being shown?